# EventArgs with methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

I'm currently wiring up a user control that has a button click that is bubbled up to a master page. I've looked at many posts to get to my current positionbut I'm not sure whether I'm done things on exactly the correct way, and whether I've got the best level of abstraction.

I'm using a custom eventargs, like this:

```
public class JumpEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    readonly int _supplierID;

    public int SupplierID
    {
        get { return _supplierID; }
    }

    public JumpEventArgs(int supplierID)
    {
        supplierID.ThrowDefault("supplierID");

        _supplierID = supplierID;
    }
}
```

And in the user control I have this this:

// should this be abstracted out of the user control?

```
    public event EventHandler<JumpEventArgs> Jumped;

    protected void LinkButtonJump_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = Jumped;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            var args = new JumpEventArgs(ProductID);
            Jumped(this, args);
        }
    }
```

My master page handler does some things that are generic to the jump event, and some that are explicit to the page. I've been pondering how to incorporate the two.

Here's the master page:

```
    void AddEventHandlers()
    {
        var jumpCtls = this.DeepFind<JumpButton>();
        jumpCtls.ForEach(uc => uc.Jumped += new EventHandler<JumpEventArgs>(JumpCtl_Clicked));
    }

    void JumpCtl_Clicked(object sender, JumpEventArgs e)
    {
        var j = new JumpEvent(e); // this is generic and can be reused
        j.AddTrack();

        MobileSearch.VisitedList.Refresh(); // this is master page only
    }
```

Here's the jump class:

// Should this be merged with the JumpEventArgs class?

```
public class JumpEvent
{
    readonly JumpEventArgs _args;

    public void AddTrack()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public JumpEvent(JumpEventArgs args)
    {
        args.ThrowNull("args");
        _args = args;
    }

    JumpEventArgs Args
    {
        get { return _args; }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure about is the master page handler, that passes the eventargs onto a generic class "JumpEvent" - something doesn't seem quite right - I may be overthinking it, but at the end of the day I'm not sure.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Is a `JumpButton` special in any way other than your custom click handler?

Comment: Sorry mason - please can you define 'special'.

Comment: "special" meaning anything that a standard button doesn't do. I know you have a custom event, but it looks like any logic that performs could just be handled with the built-in click event handler on the button, like I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a normal button for this. It doesn't appear that your JumpButton is really doing anything more than a standard Button would do, so it appears to just be adding needless complexity.

```
<asp:Button id="JumpBtn" OnClick="JumpBtn_Click" CommandArgument="Supplier3" runat="server" Text="Jump!" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void JumpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var supplierId = JumpBtn.CommandArgument; //do something with supplierId
    MobileSearch.VisitedList.Refresh();
}
```

You can dynamically bind the `CommandArgument` using inline data binding expressions. You can also cast sender to a Button class if your `JumpBtn` is supposed to be inside some sort of controls template, like a `Repeater`.

Comment: In the master page handler, 'AddTrack', needs more information than a simple command arg, otherwise its back to the database.

Comment: @dotnetnoob The code in your question doesn't show it needing anything at all. What does it need?

Comment: Ah sorry - I tried to keep some clarity and obviously removed too much. The AddTrack method, needs a couple of ID's and a couple of string variables. AddTrack then updates cookies with the info. Another question I supose is whether the jump button should carry out the updates itself - but is this too closely coupled?

Comment: @dotnetnoob The button itself should have no knowledge of any work it's supposed to be performing, which is why I advocated sticking to the standard button class and arguments. Your MasterPage should wire up to the `OnClick` event and perform any logic in its own handler. You can use `data-` attributes to pass multiple variables. Or you could serialize your arguments to JSON and put them in the CommandArgument. Or you *could* subclass button and add a property called ObjectCommandArgument, but that really seems like overkill.

Comment: I think I better understand what I need to do now mason - particlularly with regard to putting the onus on the page to carry out the work,

Answer (score 0):

It's not complicated.

Add button to page

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAction" OnClick="ButtonAction_Click" runat="server">
    Jump!
</asp:Button>
```

Pass click event to your custom event

```
protected void ButtonAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Jumped != null)
    {
        this.Jumped(this, this.ProductId);
    }
}
```

Your custom event

```
public event EventHandler<int> Jumped;
```

Then use it in master page

```
void JumpCtl_Clicked(object sender, int e)
{
    var supplierId = e;
    // Do what you want
}
```